# How can I use SVG to background on website?

Tags: css, svg, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I want to use adobe illustrator to make an svg background for my website. When I export the svg image from illustrator it has white borders and then the image won't cover the whole width of my site.. I am loosing it, so please help!

Thanks!

Screenshot of what it looks like when exported (colors are also distorted:

[image: Screenshot of what it looks like when exported (colors are also destorted..)]

Comment: Can you please provide a **[Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)** of the code you have tried?

Comment: Is the white background part of SVG?

Comment: @Matt.Hamer5 
I exported a new SVG file and it works better now, but still i have a little problem. When I use full screen (on mac) the image fills the screen, but when i minimize the browser window, the image wont cover the whole width and ca. 20-30px of the body shows on each side. My code under:

#mainImage{
    background-image: url("forside/image.svg");
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you used the SVG actually as a background and not as an image I expect that you also have used CSS. Asuming your image does not include the white borders, you could use this:

```
.your-selector {
    background-image: url('your image');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

If your SVG does contain the white borders and you don't want to change your SVGyou can change the value of your `background-size: ..% ..%` to values that make the SVG fit.